# WordPress "Site Icon" missing a trailing slash in image URL

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Working on [earlycollegecolumbus.com](http://earlycollegecolumbus.com/) hosted through bluehost.
As soon as I went live, the site logo's image url is missing a trailing slash after the domain name.
[image]

Here's what I have tried:

1. Added a trailing slash in the database "wp_options" table home URL and "normal" URL
2. Modified wpconfig.php to add

   define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://earlycollegecolumbus.com/');
3. Changed the general settings in WordPress, but it will not allow you to add a trailing slash. (WP Admin > Settings > General)
4. Updated the site URL in Bluehost settings (My sites > Settings > Site URL)

Comment: try `define('WP_HOME','https://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://example.com');`

Comment: @NickC Unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Because this happened when you went live, the web server is either striking the url. Check the .`htaccess` or ‘nginx.cong’

Look over the web servers file because iid  you find anything like the snippet below.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect permanent /
 https://www.example.com
```

Just add a trailing slash

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
Redirect permanent /
 https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: Unfortunately my .htaccess doesn't really have anything in it. I did notice that the theme used is inherited from another theme, and I wonder if it has something to do with that. I can't seem to find the nginx.cong file, do you know where that is?

Comment: Do you mean a child theme ? Also are you using baby security plugins ?

Comment: Yes, a child theme. I'm not sure what a baby security plugin is.

Comment: typo, " 3rd party security plugin" ?